# grep : get matching string before certain string

Tags: linux, grep

I have log file that contains logs in format :

```
id=tom idfrom=apple
id=tom777 idfrom=apple
id=tom 545 idfrom=facebook
id=tom.232 idfrom=yahoo
```

when I do `grep -w "tom" myfile`, I got four of them, but I only want the first one. This is especially hard because there could be whitespace in user id (ex. for the third one, the id is "tom 545"). I have to got the string before `idfrom` and after `id=`, without whitespace before or after.

How can I do this?

Edited : I just want every id, not the entire line, my desired output should be :

```
tom
tom777
tom 545
tom.232
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus Sorry I forgot that, already edited.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep to get the part between "id=" and " idfrom":

```
grep -Po '(?<=id=).*(?= idfrom)' file
```

Output:

```
tom
tom777
tom 545
tom.232
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a bash script that basically takes a single argument and searches logfile for it.  To save you from added the id= and idfrom= to your search string if you are commonly doing this type of a search.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 ]]; then
      echo "looking for: '$1'"
      grep "id=$1 idfrom=" logfile 
else
   echo "enter parameter to search for, in quotes if contains a space"
fi
```

then you can use it like this:

```
> ./search.sh tom
looking for: 'tom'
id=tom idfrom=apple

> ./search.sh "tom 545"
looking for: 'tom 545'
id=tom 545 idfrom=facebook

> ./search.sh tom.232  
looking for: 'tom.232'
id=tom.232 idfrom=yahoo
```